# 変数に値が入っていなければ値を代入し、入っていれば何もしない処理をスマートにできないでしょうか。

Tags: python

変数に値が入っていなければ値を代入し、入っていれば何もしない処理を、
現在は次のようにしています。

```
if not variable:
    variable = value
```

Noneの場合は:

```
if variable is None:
    variable = value
```

出来れば、辞書型の"variable.setdefault(value)"のように一行で書きたいと思っております。
関数を作ろうとも思ったのですが、

```
def setdefault(variable, value):
    if not variable:
        return value

variable = setdefault(variable, value)
```

のようになり、変数名を引数として渡すのもスマートでは無いなと。。

何か良い方法はないでしょうか。ご教授願います。

Comment: `variable = variable or value`で大概の場合はOK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一応、同じプログラムを三項演算子で書くと1行になります。

```
variable = value if variable is None else v
```

["PEP 505 -- None-aware operators"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/) の "Existing Alternatives" という節に他の方法も載っています。そこにも書いてあるように、[Request パッケージ](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/14a555ac716866678bf17e43e23230d81a8149f5/requests/models.py#L212)では上の書き方が使われています。

Comment: 三項演算子という手があるんですね。勉強になりました。
また、"PEP 505 -- None-aware operators"の紹介もありがとうございます!

Answer (score 4):

三項演算子風の`if`を使えば1行で書けます。

```
variable = value if variable is None else variable
```

もしくは`None`が偽と解釈されることと、ブール演算子が短絡評価されることを利用して`or`を使って書けますね。ただし、`0`や空文字列`""`、空リスト`[]`も偽と解釈されてしまうので注意が必要です。

```
In [1]: None or 1
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: 0 or 1
Out[2]: 1
```

偽として扱われる値については[こちら](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)に一覧があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
or を使用してかけるんですね。勉強になりました。